# Failing in trying to code smart cast template function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, casting

I am currently trying to code a function to perform `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` based on its input and output types in following of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. The function which i am trying to accomplish is as below:

```
#define where                       typename = typename
#define can_cast(FROM, TO)          std::is_convertible<FROM, TO>::value
#define can_dynamic_cast(FROM, TO) \
                                    can_cast(FROM, TO) && \
                                    !std::is_same<FROM, TO>::value && \
                                    std::is_class<TO>::value && \
                                    !std::is_const<FROM>::value && \ 
                                    std::is_base_of<TO, FROM>::value
#define can_static_cast(FROM, TO)   can_cast(FROM, TO)

template<typename _Tout, typename _Tin, where
    std::enable_if<
        !std::is_pointer<_Tout>::value &&
        !std::is_pointer<_Tin>::value &&
        can_cast_ptr(_Tin, _Tout)>::type>
inline _Tout* gc_ptr_cast(_Tin* const p) {
    if(can_dynamic_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*))
        return dynamic_cast<_Tout*>(p);
    if(can_dynamic_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*))
        return static_cast<_Tout*>(p);
    throw bad_cast();
}
```

But it won't work for for example `gc_ptr_cast<int>(new int(1))` due to the complaining of compiler such that:

> [..] **error:** cannot dynamic_cast 'p' (of type 'int* const') to type 'int*' (target is not pointer or reference to class)
>                `return dynamic_cast<_Tout*>(p)«;`

The compiler should process `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`!
Now i am not even sure if i am in correct path using `<type_traits>` for such purpose.

I have a half a thousand of template functions with in some of them i need to perform `static_cast` and in some of them i need to `dynamic_cast` and in half of the remaining i need to check both. The `dynamic_cast` are important in my case since it is successful in below example which is a crucial part to make things right!

```
struct base1 {};
struct base2 {};
struct derived : public base1, public base2 {};
.
.
.
derived obj;
base1* p1 = &obj;
base2* p2 = &obj;
assert(dynamic_cast<void*>(p1) == dynamic_cast<void*>(p2));  // will succeed 
assert(static_cast<void*>(p1) == static_cast<void*>(p2));    // will fail [ THIS IS WHY I CANNOT USE `static_cast` IN SOME CASES ]
```

I know there is a [smart cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0_b1/boost/serialization/smart_cast.hpp) of boost library, but i want my code just depend on C++11 std. library.

## Questions

1) What am i doing wrong?
2) How do i accomplish `gc_ptr_cast<>()`?

---

P.S: Maybe i over did the some conditions, I have put in `can_dynamic_cast` but it's OK for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use compile-time conditions in runtime-conditions. It's basically bad idea.

```
inline _Tout* gc_ptr_cast(_Tin* const p) {
    if(can_dynamic_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*))
        return dynamic_cast<_Tout*>(p);
    if(can_dynamic_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*))
        return static_cast<_Tout*>(p);
    throw bad_cast();
}
```

This should be rewritten in terms of compile-time checks, since `can_dynamic_cast` is compile-time check in your case.

I think something like this can help you:

```
template<typename _Tout, typename _Tin>
inline _Tout* ptr_cast(_Tin* const p,
typename std::enable_if<can_dynamic_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*)>::type* = 0)
{
   return dynamic_cast<_Tout*>(p);
}

template<typename _Tout, typename _Tin>
inline _Tout* ptr_cast(_Tin* const p,
typename std::enable_if<can_static_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*)>::type* = 0)
{
   return static_cast<_Tout*>(p);
}

template<typename _Tout, typename _Tin>
inline _Tout* ptr_cast(_Tin* const p,
typename std::enable_if<!can_static_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*) &&
!can_dynamic_cast(_Tin*, _Tout*)>::type* = 0)
{
   throw std::bad_cast();
}

template<typename _Tout, typename _Tin, where
    std::enable_if<
        !std::is_pointer<_Tout>::value &&
        !std::is_pointer<_Tin>::value &&
        can_cast(_Tin, _Tout)>::type>
inline _Tout* gc_ptr_cast(_Tin* const p) {
    return ptr_cast<_Tout>(p);
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is a bad idea, since when every type is known when you at compile time, so if `dynamic_cast` is not allowed its `if` will have a false condition in **compile time**.

Comment: @Dariush no, since it is not `static if`, it's just runtime if.

Comment: +1 to the nice and clean solution, it didn't come into my mind,
Thanks